# Google maps new version battery drain in offline mode

Tags: java, android, performance, google-maps

Since > 9 version of google maps services battery start draining hard in offline(or airplane) mode.

Gsm logs:

```
02-16 03:16:00.172 5795-13092/? W/ctxmgr: [AclManager]No 2 for (accnt=account#-1792900917#, com.google.android.gms(10007):UserLocationProducer, vrsn=10298000, 0, 3pPkg = null ,  3pMdlId = null). Was: 2 for 1, account#-1792900917#
02-16 03:16:00.184 5795-13092/? W/ctxmgr: [AclManager]No 2 for (accnt=account#-1253298855#, com.google.android.gms(10007):UserLocationProducer, vrsn=10298000, 0, 3pPkg = null ,  3pMdlId = null). Was: 2 for 1, account#-1253298855#
02-16 03:20:32.082 5795-25747/? W/ctxmgr: [AclManager]No 2 for (accnt=account#-1792900917#, com.google.android.gms(10007):UserLocationProducer, vrsn=10290000, 0, 3pPkg = null ,  3pMdlId = null). Was: 2 for 1, account#-179290000#
02-16 03:20:32.084 5795-25747/? W/ctxmgr: [AclManager]No 2 for (accnt=account#-1253298855#, com.google.android.gms(10007):UserLocationProducer, vrsn=10290000, 0, 3pPkg = null ,  3pMdlId = null). Was: 2 for 1, account#-1253298855#
02-16 03:27:56.240 5795-25125/? W/ctxmgr: [AclManager]No 2 for (accnt=account#-1792900917#, com.google.android.gms(10007):UserLocationProducer, vrsn=10290000, 0, 3pPkg = null ,  3pMdlId = null). Was: 2 for 1, account#-1792900917#
02-16 03:27:56.247 5795-25125/? W/ctxmgr: [AclManager]No 2 for (accnt=account#-1253298855#, com.google.android.gms(10007):UserLocationProducer, vrsn=10290000, 0, 3pPkg = null ,  3pMdlId = null). Was: 2 for 1, account#-1253298855#
```

Is it possible to suspend gsm services while there is no connection?

What is the class - AclManager?

Thanks

Comment: I need an answer for that as well.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:

> Blockquote
>   Since I hate spam and hate to be tracked for advertising by Google, I always opt out for all those things. In the last version of Google Maps for Android, there is a Location History option, that was off. Since Google Maps has the devilish behavior of trying to track you by launching itself when you don't open it yourself, it opens in the background and tries to save your location in their servers. That trigged a crazy loop because of my Location History off setting.

The only solution I found, at least if I want to keep using Google Maps, was to enable Location History. No more batery drains.

Google is copying the worst practices of Microsoft at the speed of light.